# Symfony3 Form to delete Entities

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to create a form with Symfony3. It would be a table showing all entities in a table in the database and a delete button would allow to remove rows through javascripts. Then you click the apply button and the missing entities are removed :

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | Name | Delete |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | Foo  |   X    |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | Bar  |   X    |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | Plop |   X    |
+----+------+--------+

+-------+
| Apply |
+-------+
```

From what I understand, CollectionType would allow me to do that. But I can't figure out how to use it. Precisely I don't understand at what point the entities would be linked to the form and appear through the form functions in twig.

Here is my code :

Controller:

```
class TurnamentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/turnament", name="adminTurnament")
     */
    public function indexAction( Request $request )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $turnaments = $em->getRepository( 'AppBundle:Turnament' )->findAll();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add( 'turnaments', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => TurnamentType::class,
                'entry_options' => $turnaments,
            ))
            ->add( 'apply', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Appliquer'
            ))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest( $request );
        if ( $form->isSubmitted() )
        {
            //...
        }

        return $this->render(
            'admin/turnament.html.twig',
            array(
                'turnamentsForm' => $form
            )
        );
    }
}
```

TurnamentType:

```
class TurnementType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder->add( 'delete', SubmitType::class );
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Turnament',
        ));
    }
}
```

Template:

```
{{ form_start( turnamentsForm ) }}
{% for turnament in turnamentsForm.turnaments %}
    {{ form_widget(turnament.delete) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ form_widget( turnamentsForm.apply ) }}
{{ form_end( turnamentsForm ) }}
```

I'm quite lost, I've tried to use dump() to see what is going on. It looks like the $turnaments I pass in entry_options doesn't generate TurnamentTypes...

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The 'entry_options' option for the `CollectionType` takes the options that are directly passed to the `entry_type` you enter. You are trying to pass your tournament choices as options to your `TurnamentType` directly. The `CollectionType` doesn't render any fields if it does not contain any data. Therefor your should set the tournaments as data on the collection type:

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add( 'turnaments', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => TurnamentType::class,
        'data' => $turnaments,
    ));
```

For more info on the CollectionType check out the reference guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

And some information on custom form types:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html